# Why does this code work on Atom/Live Server but does not work when I click on the file itself from file explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use the Atom IDE. I use a package on it called Live Server which shows you the current view of the website as you code. However, when I exit Atom and save it, I go to the file explorer where my files are, and I open the HTML program, everything is okay except the images, they do not show up. I've opened with several browsers.

```
img.log { /* Logo at the top left of the page */
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    float: left;
} ul.ima { /* Images line up for products */
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
} img.PhotoIMG, img.TradeIMG, img.MagazinesIMG, img.EBookIMG {
    float: inherit;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}div.banner { /* Image Banner behind "Beautiful Books" */
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url(/Images/yeet.jpg); height: 450px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Now HTML

```
<div class="IMGformat">
    <ul class="ima"> <!-- Image Line up -->
        <li class="PhotoIMG"></li>
        <img src="/Images/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="PhotoIMG" title="PhotoIMG" class="PhotoIMG">
        <li class="TradeIMG"></li>
        <img src="/Images/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="TradeIMG" title="TradeIMG" class="TradeIMG">
        <li class="MagazinesIMG"></li>
        <img src="/Images/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="MagazinesIMG" title="MagazinesIMG" class="MagazinesIMG">
        <li class="EBookIMG"></li>
        <img src="/Images/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="EBookIMG" title="EBookIMG" class="EBookIMG">
    </ul>
```

In the live server with Atom, it looks like this: [upper part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAvHW.jpg) [bottom part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srhis.png)
In the version where I click on the file/program, those images do not appear. They will be blank or have a caption.

For anyone wondering, I am recreating a website for practice, not for any profit purpose or anything malicious.

Answer (score 0):

I know zilch about Atom but I assume the issue is the format

```
src="/Images/maxresdefault.jpg"
```

the `/` at the start of the src is telling the browser to look at the root folder and move up from there. If you're opening the file up from file explorer your browser probably doesn't know what the root folder of your site is.

Can you use a file path relative to your html file such as

```
../Images/maxresdefault.jpg"
```

I assume you have some css linked and those are working fine so you could use the same sort of paths as the href attribute of your styles etc (altering the folder path a bit).

more on paths https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp